# Kotlin - possibly incorrectly reporting an unused code

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a base class for all activities in my app. I want a variable `activityClass` to be of type `<? extends BaseActivity>`. This is how I declared the variable in Kotlin:

```
 var activityClass = MainActivity::class.java as Class<out BaseActivity>
```

The problem is that in Android studio I get the part "`as Class<out BaseActivity>`" grayed out and the popup message says: "No cast needed"

If I follow the AS advice and I remove the casting, I get compiler errors when I am trying to assign the variable using other activities deriving from BaseActivity. The following code:

```
activityClass = SpecificActivity::class.java
```

gives me an error "Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: required `Class<MainActivity>`, found `Class<SpecificActivity>`".

This causes problems mainly when I am committing code changes because the options "Cleanup" and "Optimize imports" in AS commit wizard are checked, which removes "unused" code (the "as Class" part), which is in fact actually used. **The solution is not to turn these options off because I actually want them to be set to true.**

If I commit my changes, go to the class where the casting is used and undo the changes, it asks me "Undo Optimize Imports before commit?". If I confirm, I get the casting back, so I know this is causing the issue.

PS: I use Kotlin 1.0.5-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to fix this is to specify the variable type:

`var activityClass: Class<out BaseActivity> = MainActivity::class.java`

Comment: ok, that solved my problem!. Do you also know why lint tries to remove my code if it's actually used?

Comment: The cast as such is unused; the fact that it affects the inferred variable type is a side effect.